# REST with JSON works without explicit send header application/json?

Tags: json, jersey, jax-ws

I have an REST service, using jersey, and dont want to need to send "Content-Type"="application/json" in every request.

Can I set this as default to my service?

Now I'm getting error *415 Unsupported Media Type* because I'm not sending this header.

My service is like

```
@Path("/insert")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response test(Foo request) {....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved.

I changed signature from

```
public Response test(Foo request) {}
```

to

```
public Response test(@QueryParam("body") String request) {}
```

And manually desserialize JSON with

```
Foo requestObj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request, Foo.class);
```

And changed POST to GET (because I dont care about REST specification)

Note: this depends on *jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar*, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a default of the *client* on the *server*.

Nevertheless, you could use [`*/*`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#WILDCARD_TYPE):

```
@Consumes({MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE})
```

But if the client actually sends `application/json` *without* setting the proper `Content-Type`  header, the server will accept the request but have no way to deserialize the content.

So please set the proper headers with every request and response.